# Use raw SQL to insert a list in postgresql using Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

I want to insert a list of data into a table in Postgresql using Entity Framework.

Can anyone help by suggesting the syntax or an algo for that?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use raw SQL? You can do that, but you shouldn't do things the 'hard way' unless you need to. If you want to use raw SQL rather than an ORM, you are better off using Dapper.

Comment: @NickBailey I am using it because am inserting 100,000 data in it at once. I tried using bulk but I didn't find any way to achieve that using EF6. So now I want to try using this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Nick said raw sql isn't ideal especially if you are inserting 100k values,Tons of options when it comes to bulk insert i specifically use [BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFCore.BulkExtensions/) find it much easier example below

```
 using (var dbContextTransaction = _Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    //bulk insert list of user objects in users table
                    _Context.BulkInsert(list_of_users, options =>
                    {
                        options.InsertIfNotExists = true
                        options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new{x.id};

                    });
                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                    throw;

                }
            }
```

But if you are sticking to the hard route of building the raw sql query and executing it here is how i would do it,i would divide up the list into batches of 10k to avoid memory issues

```
var insert_query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (Column_1,Column_2,Column_3)VALUES";
int count=0;

            foreach (var obj in list_data)
            {
               var size = count + 1;
                if(count is 0)
                    insert_query += $"({obj.param1},{obj.param2},{obj.param3})";
                else 
                    insert_query += $",({obj.param1},{obj.param2},{obj.param3)";

                
                if(size.Equals(data.Count()))
                    insert_query += ";";

              count++;
            }
            int rows_affected = _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(insert_query);
```